# Type hints for the last argument [variable number of arguments] (python)

Tags: python, arguments, typing

I have the following function

```
def c(*cargs):
    def composed(*args,**kwargs):
        res = cargs[-1](*args,**kwargs)
        for a in cargs[:-1][::-1]:
            res = a(res)
        return res
    
    return composed
```

i.e.

```
In [33]: c(sorted,list,map)(lambda x:x*2 , [6,4,5])
Out[33]: [8, 10, 12]
```

`composed` returns the return value of the first function in cargs but gets the parameters of the last one. Any way to specify `Callable[T,U]` for both first and last function(in cargs)? So the the type of `c` is strongly defined.

Also, having all args being callable would be nice. I assume that is doable.

Comment: I dont think theres any way to do type inference for this sort of function chaining for varadic arguments (especially because you'd need to type the last function, and you can't do that if you're capturing positional arguments like `(*cargs)`), [somewhat related mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6220)

Comment: My assumption too. I asked just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting question, although I think that perhaps there would have been a better way of structuring this code. I separated out "map" here into map_like, to differentiate it from the others, and now it's fully typeable. Also, to match "sorted", arguments must support either greater than or less than, so I added this restriction. Here's the above function structure fully typed:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Protocol, TypeVar, Iterable

class SupportsDunderLT(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, __other: Any) -> bool: ...

class SupportsDunderGT(Protocol):
    def __gt__(self, __other: Any) -> bool: ...

X = TypeVar('X')
Y = TypeVar('Y', bound =SupportsDunderLT | SupportsDunderGT)
    
def c(
    *cargs: Callable[[Iterable[Y]], Iterable[Y]], 
    map_like: type[map[Y]] = map
):
    def composed(f: Callable[[X], Y], items: Iterable[X]) -> Iterable[Y]:
        res = map_like(f, items)
        for a in cargs[::-1]:
            res = a(res)
        return res
    return composed

res = c(list, sorted)(lambda x:x*2,[6,4,5])
```

However, I found when using this it complained that some of the types were unknown, due to the func inside func structure. I've also added a solution that moves this to a class structure with the same interface, as it resolves this issue:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, Protocol, TypeVar, Iterable

class SupportsDunderLT(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, __other: Any) -> bool: ...

class SupportsDunderGT(Protocol):
    def __gt__(self, __other: Any) -> bool: ...

X = TypeVar('X')
Y = TypeVar('Y', bound =SupportsDunderLT | SupportsDunderGT)

class c(Generic[X, Y]):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *cargs: Callable[[Iterable[Y]], Iterable[Y]], 
        map_like: type[map[Y]] = map
    ) -> None:
        self.cargs = cargs
        self.map_like = map_like

    def __call__(self, f: Callable[[X], Y], items: Iterable[X]) -> Iterable[Y]:
        res = self.map_like(f, items)
        for a in self.cargs[::-1]:
            res = a(res)
        return res

res = c[int,int](sorted,list)(lambda x:x*2 , [6,4,5])
```